# How can I fix "Data(contentsOf: url) crashing app"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I run `data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)` my app crashes, and I'm getting this error. I tried to add the `UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging` breakpoint but it didn't help a lot.

```
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-09-23 15:59:55.228440-0600 Biobot[15968:547259] -[LGSideMenuController isLoading]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9cf90a1a00
Warning: hit breakpoint while running function, skipping commands and conditions to prevent recursion.
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 4.1.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I don't even have an `[LGSideMenuController isLoading]` in my code. I'm really lost this time because the code worked just fine this morning. I updated my xcode to version 11, I don't know if that could be causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

You should use `Data(contentsOf: url)` only when loading data from local storage (so only url that starts with `file://`). When you are loading data from the Internet you should use URLSession:

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    DispatchQueue.main.async { //all changes to UI must be called on main thread
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        //transform your data and update UI
        self.label.text = "Loaded data: \(data)"
    }
}.resume()
```

where `self.label.text = "Loaded data: \(data)"` is some example of what you can do with your fetched data.

---

Try to avoid `try!`. Instead of it use `do{} catch {}`. Your code probably won't work as expected (it will not fix the problem, but you will be able to get more details). So in your code do:

```swift
do {
 data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
 print("\(error)")
}
```

For me, your error doesn't look like related to data loading. It looks more like an issue with memory handling, as you have a pointer that is pointing to an instance of `LGSideMenuController` and you (or one of the libraries that you are using) try to call `isLoading` method on it.

Comment: Even better, don't use `Data(contentsOf: url)` unless it is a local file URL. For remote URLs, use `URLSession`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It makes my coding better. I'll keep looking at it

Comment: It always crashes when I give data a value i don't know why